# Error with non-constant loop termination in verilog

Tags: verilog

Code was straight from the prof and everything else compiles fine, getting a consistent error with the loop given by the prof for initalization of the clock

initial begin
clk = 0;
forever #10 clk = ~clk;
end

I understand this loop is not viable as it does not terminate within a certain number of iterations, but with this statement is the goal not to initalize the clock for the program moving forward? I'm not sure how I would approach converting this to either a for loop with a constant size if that is the main issue with the loop

I've played around with the looping condition VERILOG_NON_CONSTANT_LOOP_LIMIT in the QSF file but get errors when inserted. Also my understanding is this is a complete band-aid fix and won't correct my true issues

Comment: It fails compilation with which tool? simulation? synthesis? The loop is not synthesizable and should not by synthesized at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a synthesis tool error, but your code looks like it a part of a testbench for simulation. Make sure you are using the correct tool.